# Allocating Large Tensor on multiple GPUs using Distributed Learning in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu, distributed

I am using Tensorflow Distributed learning using the following commands -

```
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"   
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0,1,2,3"

strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
    model = Basic_Model()
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=rms, metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
```

The system being used has 4 32 GB GPU devices. The following is the output of nvidia-smi -

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.87.01    Driver Version: 418.87.01    CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000004:04:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   37C    P0    65W / 300W |      0MiB / 32480MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000004:05:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   38C    P0    40W / 300W |      0MiB / 32480MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000035:03:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   33C    P0    40W / 300W |      0MiB / 32480MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000035:04:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   39C    P0    41W / 300W |      0MiB / 32480MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But after running the script to create the model, I am getting the following error -

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape [131072,65536] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc [Op:RandomUniform]
```

A tensor of shape [131072,65536] of type float would allocate 131072 * 65536 * 4 bytes i.e., 34.35 GB. And there are 4 32 GB GPUs, so why is it not allocated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MirroredStrategy creates a copy of all variables within the scope per GPU. So since the tensor size is 34.35GB, that's too large. You might be trying to use something similar to [`tf.distribute.experimental.CentralStorageStrategy`.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/experimental/CentralStorageStrategy) MirroredStrategy, in terms of gpu memory, isn't `vram * num_of_gpu`, it practically is `smallest_vram`, so in your case, Keras is working with 32GB of memory per replica, *not* 32*4=128GB.

```
strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.CentralStorageStrategy()
dataset = # some dataset
dataset = strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(dataset)
with strategy.scope():
    model = Basic_Model()
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=rms, metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
```

Example:

Tensor A is [0, 1, 2, 3] and you have four GPUs. MirroredStrategy will load:

- GPU0: [0, 1, 2, 3]
- GPU1: [0, 1, 2, 3]
- GPU2: [0, 1, 2, 3]
- GPU3: [0, 1, 2, 3]

***NOT***

- GPU0: [0]
- GPU1: [1]
- GPU2: [2]
- GPU3: [3]

As you can see, MirroredStrategy requires all your available devices to be able to hold all of the data, therefore, you're limited to your smallest device when using this strategy.